# Can we merge this two questions?

Tags: support, status-completed, merge-request, exact-duplicates

[This question](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/51711/in-the-context-of-stellar-nucleosyntheis-is-xenon-130-a-primary-or-secondary-is) was asked on EarthScience.SE on January 15 which was later migrated to here 18 hours ago. On the same date, OP posted the [same question here](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/51638/in-the-context-of-stellar-nucleosyntheis-is-xenon-130-a-primary-or-secondary-is). Now, we flagged the migrated question as duplicate of the other. Can we merge the two questions so that only the answered question remains on the site?